# What partition sizes are recommended for Ubuntu 16.04 on a 1TB hard-disk?

Tags: partitioning

What are the recommended partition sizes for my 1TB HDD?

Comment: The only correct answer: you need to set them to sizes that fit -your- needs.

Answer (score 4):

Your main partition should be of type EXT4 and a minimum of 25GB according to the Ubuntu minimum requirements.

The swap partition should match the size of your RAM, though you can increase in size to your preference.

Given you have a 1TB drive, set the swap space to match your RAM size, and then use the remaining space for the main parititon in EXT4.

Comment: my partition type is
root 30gb ext4
swap area 8gb
home 960gb.

Comment: You may need to reduce your home size and increase your root partition size to account for installed programs etc.

Comment: i will increase root partition upto 40gb.. then i reduce home how much. and i want to do 4/5 partition.. do u give me sample partition

Comment: @TheIllusionist, if you increase root to 40GB, then reduce home by whatever difference you made.

Comment: suppose my root partition is 40gb, swap area is 8gb, home is 52 gb. then remain space i want to use another four partition. is that will be correct to do that?

Comment: @TheIllusionist, yes, that's fine.